# Unable to create marklogic rest api instance

Tags: rest, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to create rest-api instance with the following configuration:
rest-api.json

```
{
 "rest-api": {
     "name": "restdb-api",
     "database": "restdb",
     "port": "8003",
     "xdbc-enabled": true,
     "forests-per-host": 1,
     "error-format": "json"
  }
}

curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -i -X POST -d @"./REST/rest-api.json"  -H "Content-type: application/json" http://localhost:8002/LATEST/rest-apis
```

The endpoint returns 201 created, but I am unable to access the created endpoint at http://localhost:8003. I have tried using other ports, but the same thing is happening. The port 8003 is not listening. Please help me solve this problem.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: MarkLogic
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="public", qop="auth", nonce="36473d01f5e45a:ND9/6NHD0sw9o2y/xad/uQ==", opaque="e9594a1b7e019a97"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 209
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: MarkLogic
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you said you are running on a local docker container, you might need to publish the port.

See Docker [Expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

Please note from the link that - "The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports."

Hope that helps!